# how to make xuartlite transmit slower

Tags: c, embedded, fpga, xilinx, uart

I have two FPGA that I am communicating using XUartLite. One of them is Spartan and other is Kintex-7. Kintex is on the send side and Spartan on the receiving end.

Relevant code for Kintex that reads a memory and sends it via uart :

```
     static volatile uint32_t data=0;
     while(len<cnt ){
      data = XIo_In32(adr);
      XUartLite_Send(&UartLite, (u8 *)&data, sizeof(uint32_t));
      adr+=sizeof(uint32_t); 
      len++;
     }
```

On the Sparatan/Receiving side: It keeps receiving until it reaches the entire length (len) given by a register:

```
    static volatile uint32_t RBuf;
    while(bt<len){
      XUartLite_DisableInterrupt(&UartLite); 
      XUartLite_Recv(&UartLite, (u8 *)&RBuf, sizeof(uint32_t));
      xil_printf("Recv: %x \n\r",RBuf);  
      XIo_Out32(ADDR+bt, RBuf); 
      XUartLite_EnableInterrupt(&UartLite); 
      bt+=sizeof(uint32_t);
    }
```

For some reason, `Recv: %x` is stalled to the previous value after 5th packet. See below( I am reading 10 address values):

```
 Recv: 0
 Recv: 1D     /*This is a control character here*/ 
 Recv: 1 
 Recv: 2 
 Recv: 3 
 Recv: 3 
 Recv: 3 
 Recv: 3 
 Recv: 3 
 Recv: 3
```

I believe it is happening because Kintex is too fast in transmitting while Spartan is slow receiving. Any ideas how to solve this would be appreciated !

Comment: Guess: XUartLite_Recv() returns a value which you are not checking to see if it's sizeof(uint32_t).

Comment: You can configure the bitrate of each xuartlite in the configuration of the IP.

Comment: @MartinJames check os sizeof(uint32_t) should always return the right number, because it is stalled with the previous value.

Comment: Is XUartLite_Recv() documented not to return until the requested number of bytes has been received?  Traditionally, blocking "receive" methods will return with whatever non-zero amount of data has been collected, or on any error condition.  For that matter, is this method documented to even be blocking?

Comment: Hmm.. if it always receives exactly as many bytes as requested, why does it bother returning the number of bytes received?

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing the function.

XuartLite_Recv() is documented to be a **non-blocking** function.

> This function will attempt to receive a specified number of bytes of data from the UART and store it into the specified buffer. This function is designed for either polled or interrupt driven modes. It is non-blocking such that it will return if no data has already received by the UART.

[source](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/hmg/le/project-home/xilinx/ise_13.2/ISE_DS/EDK/sw/XilinxProcessorIPLib/drivers/uartlite_v1_14_a/doc/html/api/xuartlite_8h.html)

If you are using the device in the default Polled Mode, you will need to check the return value as Martin James suggested.

While the documentation is unclear on this, you should also consider the possibility that, as with methods of this type on other systems, you could end up getting unaligned fractions of your 4-byte value in the results - for example, you might get 1 byte, and then 4 bytes, with that 4 bytes being the remaining 3 bytes of one value and the first byte of the next.

If you are using the device in Interrupt Mode, things are still more complicated

> In interrupt mode, this function will start receiving and then the interrupt handler of the driver will continue receiving data until the buffer has been received. A callback function, as specified by the application, will be called to indicate the completion of receiving the buffer or when any receive errors or timeouts occur. Interrupt mode must be enabled using the SetOptions function.

**Also note that when sending multi-byte values over a presumably 8-bit uart, you are going to need some scheme to make sure your transmitter and receiver agree on where the boundaries between them are.**

Comment: I looked at it too.  The documentation is very confusing.  The OP code also a little 'off' to me...

Comment: The disabling and enabling of interrupts looks suspicious to me.  As for the documentation, I agree it could be better,  I'd at least be wary of the possibility of it behaving like a typical unix-like non-blocking serial read(), until I'd proved by test against pathological timing cases or examination of the source code that it won't.

Comment: I mean - why disable the interrupt?  Sometimes, tx interrupts need to be turned off breifly to determine if the tx FIFO needs to be 'primed' with data to start the tx off, but on rx side, I never turn them off.

Comment: Well, if I were building this from scratch on a primitive embedded system I might turn of the RX interrupt while I pulled data out of the buffer, but that should be hidden in the implementation of the call (I would hope).  And there are other ways of synchronizing access anyway.

Comment: Oh - we seem to be on the same page:)  The interrupt is hardly ever actually enabled in that loop - no sooner have they been enabled than they get disabled again.

Comment: Which raises the question of if interrupt conditions met while they are disabled are deferred to fire immediately on re-enabling, or if they fire only if the condition goes from unmet to met at a time when interrupts are enabled.

Comment: Yeah - it's just 'off' somehow.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks to both you and Martin for suggestions. I have put both codes in pastebin. I am still banging my head and out of ideas. Have a look at the code and see if you get anything out of it. http://pastebin.com/KEPcwndS . http://pastebin.com/MTwwzEJe

Comment: @MartinJames Just adding your name so that you get a notification. See my reply to Chris and you above.

Comment: That looks pretty broken to me, or else its not immediately evident how it is trying to work.  Try calling the receive method for only one byte at a time, and if the return value says you got one, shifting it left in an accumulator until you have 4 bytes.  **But you'll still need to come up with some scheme to align the transmitter and receiver's sense of bytes within the 4-byte words.**  Personally I often prefer printable encodings with separators unless I'm extremely constrained on throughput - I'll even send from FPGA HDL in printable hex.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks. I have tried receive method with just sizeof(u8). It goes for 4 u8s and then gets corrupted and loops back in some strange way. I will try your idea about alignment. Do you have an example c code ?

Comment: **Are you checking the return value yet?**  And no, the code I have written for this kind of thing in the past is not usable on your system.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Do you mean return value of the Recv() ? How do I check on the value !

Comment: `if(XUartLite_Recv(&UartLite, (u8 *)&ReceiveBuffer, sizeof(uint32_t)) != sizeof(uint32_t)) xil_printf("data size: %x \n\r", ReceiveBuffer);`...This prints `0` all the time.  Same thing on send side prints the right values of data...

Comment: That snippet makes no sense at all!  Do you understand the difference between the return value of the function and its buffer?  And why != when it should be ==?